# CartoDB SQL API to Layer

Tags: carto

How to use [SQL API](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html) output to create a layer in a map?

I thought it could be achieved with [createLayer](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-3-9) passing the data directly, i.e. not with URL as second argument, but the data I am getting from SQL API has not the structure of a layer.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

To create a layer without a URL is possible. It is in the section titled, "create a layer at runtime", here

http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#runtime